# When I create a clickonce project using msbuild, the executable is double up. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a WinForms project. When I publish it to click once using the visual studio publish option, I get pretty much what I would expect in the main folder - the Application Files, the EULA (which I add as a dep), the Application Manifest (myapp.UI.winforms.application) and my setup.exe

When I publish the exact same project from the command line with MSBuild I get the identical output, except the main application is now included twice - one at Application Files => version => myapp.UI.winforms.exe, but also in the main folder as per attached.

Everything works, I just don't really want to be adding double ups to the build.

Strangely, when I build with VS, I get two copies of myapp.UI.winforms.application - one in the main directory and one in Application Files => version => myapp.UI.winforms.application, but I don't get this when I build from the command line. I would far rather this were the double up file if one needs to be though because it is only 3kb vs 9Mb

In both cases the double up files are identical.

The command I use to run the build is;

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.EXE"
  "C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\mySoln\myProj" 
  /:SolutionDir="C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\mySoln\\" 
  /t:rebuild /t:publish
  /p:PlatformTarget=x86 /p:Configuration=Release
  /p:PublishDir="C:\Users\me\Documents\Deploy\web\\
```